# How to determine the selected cell of a Ext.grid.Panel in ExtJS 4?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

how can i get the selected cell of a Ext.grid.Panel?
In ExtJS 3 it was possible via:

```
grid.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCell()
```

In Ext 4 there is

```
grid.getSelectionModel().selected
```

but this only gives me the record.

Comment: Did you use cellselectionmodel?

Comment: yes i'm using the cellselectionmodel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be a more direct way to do this but the following seems to work for me:

```
grid.view.getCellByPosition(grid.getSelectionModel().getCurrentPosition());
```

Comment: I'm not at work anymore, so i can't try...
What i did as a workaround, was to 'misuse' the select-event and store the cell and column in an own variable.

Comment: Yeah, that was my first thought too, until I read through the source code and came up with the above!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up needing the actual column that the user was clicking on and discovered the following:

```
grid.panel.columns[grid.getSelectionModel().getCurrentPosition().column]
```

Don't forget to apply:

```
    selType : 'cellmodel'
```

to your grid to make sure you can select cells!

Answer (score 0):

Use the beforeedit listener and context.record to get the desired row

```
this.editing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
        clicksToEdit: 1,
        listeners: {
            beforeedit: function (obj) {
                var MyColumnValue = obj.context.record.get('YourColumnName');
                 // or maybe to clear the value of this cell
                 obj.context.record.set('YourColumnName', null);
        }
      }
 });
```