# Selecting specific cells in a grid - Ext JS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have set up a controller here that listens for a click on a grid row:

```
   init: function() {
            this.control({
                'mygrid': {
                    select: this.viewDesc //On click...
                }
            });
        },
```

Right now this event fires no matter what cell is clicked on. However, I want to listen for the click of a specific column/cells.

How could this be achieved?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042176/how-to-determine-the-selected-cell-of-a-ext-grid-panel-in-extjs-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cellclick` event for grid, and identify on which cell user has clicked, it would be something like :

```
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'mygrid': {
            cellclick: function(view, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts) {
                // if clicked on cell 4, show popup otherwise ignore
                if(cellIndex == 3) { // cellIndex starts from 0
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Selected Record', 'Name : ' + record.get('firstname') + ' ' + record.get('lastname'));
                }
            }
        }
    });
},
```

Above code snippet is taken from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19218089/1065180) to your previous question

Comment: Thank you Nandkumar, you are golden

Comment: Is there any way to select the cellIndex from a different value? Such as a dataIndex?

Comment: What I mean is, instead of 'if(cellIndex == 3)', could I do something like 'if(cellIndex.dataIndex == "popup")' ?

Comment: I am not sure, I think it would be possible with `view`, I will check and tell you